# NOT NULL constraint failed when sending a post request with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with my API. When I'm sending a Post request to create a new Message I got the following error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_message.channel_id

The models:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        users = models.ManyToManyField(Account)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    
class Message(models.Model):
    
        user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        content = models.TextField(blank=False)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

The serializers:

```
   class ChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        users = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Channel
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
        channel = ChannelSerializer(read_only=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Message
            fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializers For The User Object"""

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ["email","password","username","id"]
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 8 }}

   def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create the user with encrypted password"""
        return Account.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update The user"""
        user = super().update(instance,validated_data)
        return user
```

And the views:

```
class ChannelView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """View for the channels"""
    serializer_class = ChannelSerializer
    queryset = Channel.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retrieve channels linked to the authenticated user"""
        return self.queryset.filter(users = self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """ Create a new channel with users set in the request as users"""
        serializer.save(users = self.request.data.get('users'))


class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """View for the messages"""

    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    queryset = Message.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """ Create a new message with the current user set as user """
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

The idea was to receive the whole object, not just pk, when sendind a get request for a message or channel, which works. But then the post request doesn't work anymore.

When I erase channel = ChannelSerializer(read_only=True) from the message serializer everything work well but then it's not the behavior that I want.

So obviously I'm struggling with nested serializer and I didn't manage to figure out what happens with the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield).

I know that NOT NULL constraint failed means that a non nullable field doesn't recieve a value but I don't get why it would be channel ID...

here's different payloards i'v tried:

```
{     
    "user": {
              "email": "test@test.test",
              "username": "test",
               "id": 2
                },
        "channel": {
            "id": 2,
            "users": [
                {
                    "email": "vincent@yahoo.fr",
                    "username": "username",
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "email": "test@test.test",
                    "username": "test",
                    "id": 2
                }
            ],
            "name": "Channel 2",
            "created_date": "2023-03-03T09:45:24.184499Z"          
    },
    "content" : "hello" 
}
```

or

```
{     
    "user": 1,
    "channel": 1,
    "content" : "hello" 
}

{     
    "user": [1],
    "channel": [1],
    "content" : "hello" 
}
```

Full Error:

```
[03/Mar/2023 15:43:15] "POST /chat/message/ HTTP/1.1" 500 201970
Internal Server Error: /chat/message/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_message.channel_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 55, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create 
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\chat\views.py", line 34, in perform_create
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)  
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)       
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 671, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 812, in save  
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 863, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1006, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1047, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)       
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1791, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1660, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vince\Desktop\Code\Rep\ChatProject\ChatProject---API\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_message.channel_id
```

Comment: can you show me the payload that you are sending on post request

Comment: why are you sending "user" in a list form it takes just id like this { "user": 2, "channel": 2, "content": "whatever content you want to send"} send like like this

Comment: Yep it doesn't work aswell, same django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_message.channel_id error

Comment: what error it has been shown?

Comment: But {     
    "name": "2",
    "users": [1,2]
} would work for a post request for a channel

Comment: yup it will work because ManyToMany Field takes a list of objects while Foreign Key takes just single object

Comment: Yes but  { "user": 2, "channel": 2, "content": "whatever content you want to send"} doens't work aswell, I put the full traceback at the end of the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252278/discussion-between-tanveer-ahmad-and-vincentab).